# MongoDB records are deleted after deploy project to dokku

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline, digital-ocean, dokku

I use https://github.com/jeffutter/dokku-mongodb-plugin on digital ocean.

So, after deploy my sails.js app mongoDB database is empty.

How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After Every deploy I need to make $ dokku mongodb:start. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the environment variable `NODE_ENV=production` when deploying your sails.js application. This will ensure the migration strategy is set to `safe`, and your data will not be deleted on reboot.

Comment: No. I fixed it. The trouble was in not running mongodb after deploy to dokku. After every deploy I need to use $ dokku mongodb:start

Comment: Set migration strategy to **safe** and it will be fixed.